# Set the value of UIPickerView right after its data is loaded

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview

I have developed something very similar to DateCell Demo from Apple. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/DateCell/Introduction/Intro.html

The only difference is that I have a UIPickerView instead of a UIDatePicker. And whenever the cell is touched a new UIPickerView is instantiated and added to the cell below once touched again it is removed from the cell. And the part I have problem with is to select a specific item in the UIPickerView.

Here is some code:

```
var selectedPlatform = "Mac"
var platformPickerDataSource = ["iOS", "Mac", "PC", "Android"]


func updatePlatformPicker()
{
    if let indexPath = platformPickerIndexPath {
        let associatedPlatformPickerCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        if let targetedPlatformPicker = associatedPlatformPickerCell?.viewWithTag(Constants.kPlatformPickerTag) as! UIPickerView? {

            targetedPlatformPicker.dataSource = self
            targetedPlatformPicker.delegate = self
            // I cannot do selectRow(selectedPlatform, inComponent: 0,
  animated : true) here since the row since the rows in the UIPickerView are not set
        }
    }
}
```

So my questions is, if you refer to the code from Apple, where can I set?

```
selectRow(selectedPlatform, inComponent: 0,
  animated : true)
```

Edit: (I added the whole code, which is basically the swift version of Apple's DateCell Example and DatePicker replaced with a UIPickerView)

```
import UIKit

class PickerTableViewController: UITableViewController, UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate {

var platformPickerIndexPath : NSIndexPath?


var pickerCellRowHeight: CGFloat = 140


var selectedPlatform = "Mac"
var platformPickerDataSource = ["iOS", "Mac", "PC", "Android"]

private struct Constants {
    static let kPlatformCellID: String = "platformCell"
    static let kPlatformPickerID: String = "platformPicker"
    static let kOtherCell: String = "otherCell"
    static let kPlatformRow : Int = 1
    static let kPlatformPickerTag : Int = 99
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

// MARK: - Table view data source

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    var rows = 3

    if hasInlinePlatformPicker()
    {
        rows = 4
    }
    return rows
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell : UITableViewCell?

    print("\(indexPath.row)")

    var cellID = Constants.kOtherCell

    if indexPathHasPicker(indexPath)
    {
        cellID = Constants.kPlatformPickerID
    }
    else if indexPathHasPlatform(indexPath)
    {
        cellID = Constants.kPlatformCellID
    }

    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellID)

    var modelRow = indexPath.row
    if (platformPickerIndexPath != nil && platformPickerIndexPath?.row <= indexPath.row) {
        modelRow -= 1
    }

    if cellID == Constants.kPlatformCellID
    {
        cell?.textLabel?.text = "Select a platform"
        cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = selectedPlatform
    }
    else if cellID == Constants.kOtherCell
    {
        cell?.textLabel?.text = "Other Cell"
    }
    return cell!
}


func indexPathHasPicker(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool
{
    return hasInlinePlatformPicker() && platformPickerIndexPath?.row == indexPath.row
}

func indexPathHasPlatform(indexPath : NSIndexPath) -> Bool
{
    var hasPlatform = false
    if indexPath.row == Constants.kPlatformRow || (hasInlinePlatformPicker() && (indexPath.row == Constants.kPlatformRow + 1))
    {
        hasPlatform = true
    }
    return hasPlatform
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)

    if cell?.reuseIdentifier == Constants.kPlatformCellID
    {
        displayInlinePlatformPickerForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    }
    else
    {
        tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)
    }

}

func displayInlinePlatformPickerForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath : NSIndexPath)
{
    // display the platform picker inline with the table content
    tableView.beginUpdates()
    var before = false

    if hasInlinePlatformPicker()
    {
        before = platformPickerIndexPath?.row < indexPath.row
    }


    let sameCellClicked = (platformPickerIndexPath?.row == indexPath.row + 1)

    // remove any picker cell if it exists
    if hasInlinePlatformPicker()
    {

        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([NSIndexPath(forRow: platformPickerIndexPath!.row, inSection: 0)], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
        platformPickerIndexPath = nil
    }

    if (!sameCellClicked)
    {
        // hide the old picker and display the new one

        let rowToReveal = (before ? indexPath.row - 1 : indexPath.row)
        let indexPathToReveal = NSIndexPath(forRow: rowToReveal, inSection: 0)


        togglePlatformPickerForSelectedIndexPath(indexPathToReveal)

        platformPickerIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: indexPathToReveal.row + 1, inSection: 0)
    }

    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    tableView.endUpdates()

    updatePlatformPicker()
}


func updatePlatformPicker()
{


    if let indexPath = platformPickerIndexPath {
        let associatedPlatformPickerCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
        if let targetedPlatformPicker = associatedPlatformPickerCell?.viewWithTag(Constants.kPlatformPickerTag) as! UIPickerView? {

            targetedPlatformPicker.dataSource = self
            targetedPlatformPicker.delegate = self

        }
    }
}


func togglePlatformPickerForSelectedIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{

    tableView.beginUpdates()

    let indexPaths = [NSIndexPath(forRow: indexPath.row + 1, inSection: 0)]




    // check if 'indexPath' has an attached picker below it
    if hasPickerForIndexPath(indexPath)
    {
        // found a picker below it, so remove it
        tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths, withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    }
    else
    {
        // didn't find a picker below it, so we should insert it
        tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPaths, withRowAnimation: .Fade)


    }

    tableView.endUpdates()


}


func hasPickerForIndexPath(indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool
{

    var hasPlatformPicker = false
    let targetedRow = indexPath.row + 1

    let checkPlatformPickerCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: targetedRow, inSection: 0))

    let checkPlatformPicker  = checkPlatformPickerCell?.viewWithTag(Constants.kPlatformPickerTag)

    hasPlatformPicker = checkPlatformPicker != nil
    return hasPlatformPicker
}



func hasInlinePlatformPicker() -> Bool
{
    return platformPickerIndexPath != nil
}


override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return (indexPathHasPicker(indexPath) ? pickerCellRowHeight : tableView.rowHeight)
}

// MARK: - Platform Picker View Data Source and Delegates
func numberOfComponentsInPickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
    return platformPickerDataSource.count
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {
    return platformPickerDataSource[row]
}

func pickerView(pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    print("Platform Selected: \(platformPickerDataSource[row])")

    var targetedCellIndexPath: NSIndexPath?

    if hasInlinePlatformPicker() {
        // inline picker: update the cell's above the picker cell
        //
        targetedCellIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: platformPickerIndexPath!.row - 1, inSection: 0)
    }

    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(targetedCellIndexPath!)

    cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = platformPickerDataSource[row]
}


}
```

Comment: Have you tried dispatch_async in main thread??

Comment: Where are you calling your `updatePlatformPicker()` function? What does your `ViewController` class look like?

Comment: I added the whole code.